# php mycrypt using session id as key

Tags: php, session

I successfully use  mycrypt to encrypt id's in an admin panel as they are often seen in the URL. I have previously added a key manually as I code, but this time I plan to use the users account id which is kept in a session. Is this a good way, or should I keep with a fixed key throughout the site.

Thanks

Comment: There is a big difference between a session id and a user account id that happens to be stored in a session. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: when the user logs in I store their account id in a session so I can query the database without passing their account id from page to page.  Hope that makes sense

Comment: Session ID is stored in a cookie or propagated via URL. You used a publically available key to encrypt something that doesn't even have to be passed around via URL (some sort of admin ID). It kinda doesn't make sense, does it?

Comment: ok, say the account_id in the session is used  to get a list of units they rent, the unit_id is then encrypted in a "Edit" link to say edit it.  I don't want unit_id value on show anywhere...not even in the source....so I encrypt it using their session account id as the key....perhaps I have over thinking this or being over cautions....I was just thinking that the session holding the account id could be used as a dynamic key for encryption and decryption as its going to be present throughout their time in the admin panel

Comment: Session ID is stored in your cookie. It is used by the server to find the file (or database record) that is named using that session ID. The file (or db record) contains the data of the session. So at any time, all the DATA is on the server, while the actual filename or record lookup is stored in a cookie. So yes, you're overthinking a simple problem apparently, and you haven't made anything safer, just slightly more complex for absolutely no gain.

Answer (score 0):

Never pass SESSION IDs over URLs, even if encrypted (though it's weird and still quite unsafe). Transferring SESSION IDs has been deprecated long time ago by PHP (session.use_trans_id=0). Session ID is transferred automatically by browser, you don't need to take care of it at all.

The only use case might be if you want forcibly allow browsers with disabled cookies, then you would need to append such a parameter to all links (mimicking deprecated bahaviour). However:

- it would be still great security risk, since mostly attackers and malicious webbots disable cookies,
- encrypting in any ways makes no sense coz string can be still hijacked and server will decrypt into original session ID

So you just pull out userID stored in session and don't worry about transferring session ID over URL.